# Derivation of position equation in simple harmonic motion, using KE

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I'm trying to get the position equation in SHM, using the equation:
$$KE = {K \over2 }{(A^2 - x^2)}$$
This is what I tried:
$${mv^2 \over2 }={K \over2 }{(A^2 - x^2)}$$
$${v} = {\sqrt{K \over{m}}} {\sqrt{A^2 - x^2}}$$
$$ {dx \over{dt}} = {\sqrt{K \over{m}}} {\sqrt{A^2 - x^2}}$$
$$\int{dx \over{{\sqrt{A^2 - x^2}}}} = \int{\sqrt{K \over{m}}} dt$$
Is this thought process correct? If yes, what would be the next step to get to:
$$x=Asin(\sqrt{K \over{m}}t+\phi_0)$$

Comment: so your kinetic energy is negative when $\vert x\vert>A$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is correct so far.
The next step for solving
$$\int{dx \over{{\sqrt{A^2 - x^2}}}} = \int{\sqrt{K \over{m}}} dt$$
is to actually do the integration.
The $t$-integral is easy, but for the $x$-integral you probably need a good math handbook.

$$\arcsin\frac{x}{A}=\sqrt{\frac{K}{m}}t+\phi_0$$

Then solve for $x$
$$x=A\sin\left(\sqrt{\frac{K}{m}}t+\phi_0\right)$$

Comment: I see. When I tried to input the equation into WolframAlpha, it yielded $$tan^{-1} ({x \over{\sqrt{{A^2-x^2}}}})=\sqrt{K \over{m}} t$$ Do you perhaps know why that is?

Comment: @user376722 Because $$\arctan {x \over{\sqrt{{A^2-x^2}}}} = \arcsin\frac{x}{A}$$
and WolframAlpha sometimes is not smart enough to choose the simpler one.

Answer (score 0):

The next step is to do this integral
$$\int{dx \over{{\sqrt{A^2 - x^2}}}},$$
which effectively "solves for $x$".

(Note the integral on the right-hand side won't bring in the sine function.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually evaluate the integrals.

$$\int\sqrt{K/m}dt = \sqrt{K/m}\int dt = \sqrt{K/m}\;\; t +C_1$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{A^2-x^2}}=Arcsin(x/A) + C_2$$

So

$$Arcsin(x/A) + C_2 = \sqrt{K/m}\;\; t +C_1$$

$$Arcsin(x/A) =  \sqrt{K/m}\;\; t +  (C_1 -C_2)$$

$$Arcsin(x/A) =  \sqrt{K/m}\;\; t + \phi_0$$

$$(x/A) =  sin(\sqrt{K/m}\;\; t + \phi_0)$$

$$x =  A*sin(\sqrt{K/m}\;\; t + \phi_0)$$